# Proof about Hermitian matrices

Tags: linear-algebra

> Consider Hermitian matrices $M^1$, $M^2$, $M^3$, $M^4$ that obey $$M^iM^j+M^jM^i = 2\delta^{ij}I,\qquad i,j=1,2,3,4$$ Show that the eigenvalues of $M^i$ are $\pm 1$

I've found that $\pm 1$ are eigenvalues by doing this: Suppose $i=j$, then $$2(M^i)^2=2I \\ \implies (M^i)^2 = I^2 \\ \implies (M^i-I)(M^i+I)=0$$ which implies that $\pm 1$ are eigenvalues.  What I'm not seeing how to do is to show that these are the only eigenvalues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$u$ is an eigenvector associated at $c$ implies $M(u)=cu, M^2(u)=c^2u=u$ since $M^2=I$. This implies that $c^2=1$.